# Swiper on 9.01 fix pack 7

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I just installed fix-pack7 and discoverd that my swiper plug-in was gone
Tried to reinstall, but message says "No acceptable features were found.." when installing from update site
Anyone experience the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if the feature is still installed, but disabled? Go to:
File-> Application -> Application Management 
and then try to find the Swiper Feature in that list. See if it has a 'disabled' icon, and if so, enabled the feature again.

It sounds like it would not suggest to install the feature because it thinks that it already has the feature installed (albeit disabled).

I have heard in previous upgrades, that some installed features become disabled after upgrade.

If this is not the case then please let me know. And I will look into it further.

I have not upgraded to FP7 yet, but if anyone reading this has upgraded to FP7 and has Swiper working fine please add a comment or let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Between my original posting and your answer, I uninstalled Swiper manually following  Mikkel Flindt Heisterberg exelent guide:http://lekkimworld.com/2010/03/17/complete_guide_to_manually_uninstalling_plugins_from_lotus_notes.html.
I am now back up and running on fp7 with Swiper.  The problems made me realize how dependent I am on this great peace of software of yours I my daily works. Thanks
Problem solved :)

Comment: thanks for your kind words! I'm glad to hear you are back up and running

Comment: Just one little thing while we are at it. Swiper will not run automatically in my project. I think it did in the beginning, but it stopped. I now have to run manually before commits.  I was hoping a reinstallation would do the trick, but I’m out of luck. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have 'build automatically' on or off?

Comment: ok, and do you use the right click 'Team Development -> Sync with on disk project?' if so, unfortunately swiper cannot get involved when the sync is triggered that way. Only during a build.
I have been working with XPages team to get this modified so that Swiper can do what it needs to do, however it has been a while and I am not sure if it is ever going to happen :(
I use build automatically and Swiper should be triggered when this happens, can you turn on Build Automatically to verify if it works ok then?

Comment: I usually don’t have to sync with ODP manually, it is set up to run automatically and it works fine most of the time
Did a quick test with Build Automatically, does not seems to help. It causes to many issues for me anyway, so I can't use it in my daily work. It would help A LOT, if I was able to right-click on the top level of a (java) package structure, in the navigator view,   and run the _filter selected_ command. Now I have to expand each sub-package and get to the individual files to do manual filtering.

Comment: ok I will have a look into it. one last suggestion, what about if you remove Swiper from the NSF and then add it again?

Comment: Tried that, does not seem to help